# is it possible to condense an object to a point?

Tags: condensed-matter

When matter is condensed the mass stays the same and we also know that only the volume and density are the only other two effected variables. But is there a point in which the matter cannot condense anymore? Or a point in which the volume cannot decrease anymore?

Comment: Google *planck length*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a [black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).
Some are not stable due to too little mass, or other problems. 
Example:[Photon Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere)